# Loop to set OrderBy/ThenBy for multiple columns

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm using DataTables.Mvc library for use with jQuery DataTables.

One of the methods is `GetSortedColumns()` which returns an array containing configurations for each column to be sorted.

Of interest in this object are the `Name` and `SortDirection` properties. `Name` is also the database table field name. `SortDirection` is either `asc` or `desc`.

At first `ThenBy` and `ThenByDescending` were undefined symbols, so I created `ordered` as `IOrderedQueryable`. This resolves the symbols, but I don't see any effect of these. Neither OrderBy, OrderByDescending, ThenBy nor ThenByDescending have any effect on the order of records in `filteredRecords`.

In Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult GetUserSelections([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestModel)
{
    // Column Sort
    var filteredRecords = db.AspNetSelectorInputs.Select(si => si);
    var sortedColumns = requestModel.Columns.GetSortedColumns();
    var count = 0;

    foreach (var column in sortedColumns)
    {
        var ordered = filteredRecords as IOrderedQueryable<AspNetSelectorInput>;

        filteredRecords =
            column.SortDirection == DataTables.Mvc.Column.OrderDirection.Ascendant
            ? count == 0
                ? ordered.OrderBy(c => column.Name)
                : ordered.ThenBy(c => column.Name)
            : count == 0
                ? ordered.OrderByDescending(c => column.Name)
                : ordered.ThenByDescending(c => column.Name);

        count++;
    }

    filteredRecords = filteredRecords.Select(si => si).Skip(requestModel.Start).Take(requestModel.Length);

....
```

Can anyone see why this doesn't affect ordering of `filteredRecords`?

Is there a better way?

Comment: is your `count` never `==` to `0`?

Comment: Sure. It's initialized to 0

Comment: I think it depends on which parts of the project you're using. For example, if using dapper integration you need to use the `GetSortPredicate` method which will take the field name and turn it into an actual sort on that field. Now you are sorting by the column name itself, so everything has the same sorted-by value. See the sample projects or browse the source code for how some of this is done. Dapper extensions: https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.aspnet/blob/dev/src/DataTables.AspNet.Extensions.DapperExtensions/DapperExtensions_Exensions.cs - Other tools exist depending on your data source

Answer (score 0):

It is sorting, on exactly what you've asked it to. But the lambda expressions aren't doing what you think. For example, you're doing `.OrderBy(c => column.Name)`, which is sorting using a literal value of the *name of the column* which has the same value for every item in the collection (notice how the thing it is sorting on is not affected by `c`), so it *appears* not to sort your collection. For example, you might as well be doing `.OrderBy(c => "Hello")`.

You would need to do something like `.OrderBy(c => c.YourChoiceOfPropertyName)`. Except you can't do that because (presumably) the name of the property is a string value in `column.Name`. So you'll need to use reflection within the lambda to get the value of that property using `c` as the instance. This will need fixing on all the lambdas. For example, inside the loop:

```
var propertyInfo=typeof(AspNetSelectorInput)
    .GetProperty(column.Name);
```

And replacement lambda expressions:

```
c=>propertyInfo.GetValue(c)
```

P.S. the two instances of `.Select(si => si)` seem to be redundant, unless I am missing something.